# Autohotkey Multiple hotkeys at same time (Middle button, Left button, Right button of the mouse pressed at once)

Tags: mouse, autohotkey, media-player

I'v been working on a way to controll music/media with my mouse, so far i can do all these:

Middle and Right button play next song

```
Mbutton & RButton::Send {Media_Next}
```

Middle and Left button play Previus song

```
Mbutton & LButton::Send {Media_Prev}
```

Middle pressed and rolled Up Increases sound (doesnt stop the use of middle click elsewhere)

Middle pressed and rolled Down Decreases sound (doesnt stop the use of middle click elsewhere)

```
#IfWinActive

Mbutton up::

`if a_priorhotkey not in wheelup,wheeldown`

    `send {Mbutton}`
return

#if getkeystate("Mbutton", "p")

Wheelup::Send {Volume_Up}

Wheeldown::Send {Volume_Down}
```

**But now i need to press ALL 3 (Lbutton + Mbutton + Rbutton) at the same time,
to send {Media_Play_Pause}** And its not working with Lbutton & Mbutton & Rbutton...

Any ideas? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possibility:

```
#if getkeystate("Lbutton", "p") and getkeystate("Rbutton", "p")
MButton::Send {Media_Play_Pause}
#if
```

Explanation (albeit mostly straightforeword):

1. Line 1: If the `LButton` and `RButton` are pressed
2. Line 2: `MButton` means `Send` `Media Pause/ Play`
3. Line 3: End context sensitive hotkeys

---

Full Script:

```
#IfWinActive

Mbutton & RButton::Send {Media_Next}
Mbutton & LButton::Send {Media_Prev}

Mbutton up::
if a_priorhotkey not in wheelup,wheeldown

    send {Mbutton}
return

#if getkeystate("Mbutton", "p")
Wheelup::Send {Volume_Up}
Wheeldown::Send {Volume_Down}

#if getkeystate("Lbutton", "p") and getkeystate("Rbutton", "p")
MButton::Send {Media_Play_Pause}
#if
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the help, i'v just tested here and I think this only works if I press the keys exactly at the same time, because otherwise it will just play the next or previus songs due to the other hotkeys.

Comment: Try holding the `Left Mouse Button` and the `Right Mouse Button` Down together first before pressing the `Middle Mouse Button`. If I understood correctly, there isn't currently a `LButton & RButton` hotkey in your script, so once you hold down both of them, pressing the `MButton` afterwards should activate this new block of code instead of any of the previous ones. In any case, I'll update my answer to include the full script that worked for me.